# WCF Exception Handling #2

Tags: wcf

I am having N number of WCF service method. I want to implement the exception handling. My service will be consumed by .net and non .net client. Is Fault contract is the only way to implement the exception handling? If it is means how can i avoid implementing to all the methods in my service. How can i implement Exception handling in one place to handle the exception of all the methods in my service. Kindly provider some set of codes to easily under stable.

Here is my sample code.

---

MyFaultContract

---

```
[DataContract()]  
public class FleetCustomException  
{  
    [DataMember()]  
    public string Title;  
    [DataMember()]  
    public string ExceptionMessage;  
    [DataMember()]  
    public string InnerException;  
    [DataMember()]  
    public string StackTrace;          
}
```

MyServiceContract

---

```
[ServiceContract]  
public interface IAddress  
{  
    [OperationContract]  
[FaultContract(typeof(FleetCustomException))]  
    bool SaveAddress(string address1, string address2, string address3, string city, string province, string postalCode,string country,bool isDeleted, int createdBy, DateTime createdDate, int lastModifiedBy, DateTime lastModifiedDate);  

    [OperationContract]  
[FaultContract(typeof(FleetCustomException))]  
    bool DeleteAddress(Int64 addressID, int lastModifiedBy);  

    [OperationContract]  
[FaultContract(typeof(FleetCustomException))]  
    List<Address> GetAllAddresses();  
}
```

Service

---

```
public class SettingsService : IAddress  
{  

    #region IAddress Members  

    public bool SaveAddress(string address1, string address2, string address3, string city, string province,string postalCode,string country, bool isDeleted,int createdBy, DateTime createdDate, int lastModifiedBy, DateTime lastModifiedDate)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            Address address = new Address(0, address1, address2, address3, city, province, postalCode, country, isDeleted,createdBy, createdDate, lastModifiedBy, lastModifiedDate);  
            return address.Insert();  

        }  
        catch (FaultException ex)  
        {  

          FleetCustomException ex = new FleetCustomException();  
          ex.Title = "Error Funtion:SaveAddress()";  
      ex.ExceptionMessage = "Error occur while doing save address function.";  
          ex.InnerException = "Inner exception message from serice";  
          ex.StackTrace = "Stack Trace message from service.";  
          throw new FaultException(ex,"Reason: Testing the Fault contract") ;  
        }  
    }     




    public bool DeleteAddress(Int64 addressID, int lastModifiedBy)  
    {  
        Address address = new Address(addressID, lastModifiedBy);  
        return address.Delete();  
    }  

    public List<Address> GetAllAddresses()  
    {  

        Address address = new Address();  
        return address.GetAllAddresses();  
    }  
    #endregion
```

}

config in Service layer includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" in `<serviceDebug>`

---

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

### Consume Method

```
   try  
   {  
      MySettingsService.SettingsService  proxy = new MySettingsService.SettingsService();
      proxy .SaveAddress(Address1TextBox.Text, Address2TextBox.Text, "", "", "", "641025", "", false, 1, DateTime.Now, 0, DateTime.Now);  
    }  
    catch (FaultException<MyCalculatorService.CustomException> ex)  
     {  
        //Process the Exception
     }
```

---

i have to implement to all my service methods i am having more than 100 method is there any way to achieve it quickly as well as effectively

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's wrong with not handling the exceptions at all?

Comment: Hi john if i handle only the exception. The other programs which not in .net framework will not understand the exception. so that WCF fault contract will send XML soap based exception.

Comment: There will still be a SOAP Fault, just not a detailed one.

Answer (score 0):

A FaultContract is the appropriate "SOAP" way to handle errors. The SOAP standard defines the fault message elements.

The down side to this in WCF is that you need to specify the `[FaultContract]`on each WCF service operation, so if you have a lot of methods, you have to define it a lot of places.
(There is actually a way to programatically add the fault-contract at WCF service startup time to prevent having to declare it on every method, if I can dig up the code somewhere...)

Also, if you want some central place to handle errors in your WCF service, you can implement [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) which will get called by WCF when any unhandled exceptions occur.

---

Alternatively, you could just structure your messages in such a way that they always have the option to include an error message. For example:

```
[OperationContract]
SaveAddressResult SaveAddress(...);

[DataContract]
public class SaveAddressResult : Result
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

---

*Additional note:* it is bad practice to send your exception and stack trace back to the client! It would potentially contain stack trace info or other information that your customer should not know about. For example if you had a service method that tried to validate a login using a SQL query, and the DB itself caused an Exception, the client might get back your table and column names or even the DB name in the exception message thrown by the query.  Your exception messages should always be sanitized, and stripped down to just the information that the customer needs!

One good example of this is any string input that goes into the DB. Doing something like:

```
public Save(string someData)
{
    sqlCommand.Statement = "insert into myTable (myColumn) values (" + someData + ")";
    sqlCommand.Execute();
}
```

If the column being inserted into is lets say `VARCHAR(256)` and the user now sends your service a 500 character string, the client is going to get back a Fault message that includes something like "value too large for column myTable.myColumn".  That is implementation and internal detail that your client should never know about.

Comment: What is the best way for exception handling in wcf.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler` interface to handle all errors in a centralized place.

I would suggest you to go through this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26320/WCF-Error-Handling-and-Fault-Conversion